# Eloquent ORM and postgres migration - Is it possible to assign an expression default value?

Tags: postgresql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I was reading [an article on secure storage of credentials with postgres](https://www.meetspaceapp.com/2016/04/12/passwords-postgresql-pgcrypto.html) which recommended randomized `uuids` vs an autoincrementing `id`.

In raw postgresql it would be something like:

`id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY`

However, with eloquent I can't figure out how to achieve something like this. The [eloquent docs for 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#column-modifiers) mention `->storedAs($expression)` which is unfortunately limited to MySQL. Is this simply not possible with postgres?

Comment: Try `->default(DB::raw('gen_random_uuid()'))`

Comment: @Aboudeh87 this worked perfectly! It's surprising the `DB::raw` notation isn't mentioned anywhere in that documentation. Could you post your solution as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: I wrote an answer with documentation link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ->default(DB::raw('gen_random_uuid()'));

It is exists in [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions) documentation